# conversion of column datatype from varchar to Date in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

i have a column whose datatype is Varchar and i use a select query which fetch the data from given range based on that coloumn.now i want to convert this column from varchar to date so that my query works fine. i am using Mysql as backend database . i dont want to change the column datatype to Date in Mysql Schema but change at run time through some sql function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CAST()

http://forums.devshed.com/firebird-sql-development-61/casting-a-varchar-to-date-477361.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast